# python: dictionary to string, custom format?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

currently I'm displaying keys only, each in new line:

```
'<br/>'.join(mydict)
```

how do I display them like *key*:: *value*, each in the new line?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Go through the `dict.items()` iterator that will yield a key, value tuple:

```
'<br/>'.join(['%s:: %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in d.items()])
```

Updated with modern [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) notation:

```py
'<br/>'.join([f'{key}:: {value}' for key, value in d.items()])
```

Comment: Less verbose if you don't unpack the tuple: `'<br/>'.join(['%s:: %s' % kv for kv in d.items()])`

Answer (score 11):

That, or an even cooler solution using `join` to join both items *and* the (key,value) pairs, avoiding the now-obsolete `%` interpolation, using only a single dummy variable `_`, and dropping the redundant list comprehension:

```
"<br/>".join(":: ".join(_) for _ in mydict.items())
```

Be aware that dicts have no ordering, so without `sorted()` you might not get what you want:

```
>>> mydict = dict(a="A", b="B", c="C")
>>> ", ".join("=".join(_) for _ in mydict.items())
'a=A, c=C, b=B'
```

This also only work when all keys and values are strings, otherwise `join` will complain. A more robust solution would be:

```
", ".join("=".join((str(k),str(v))) for k,v in mydict.items())
```

Now it works great, even for keys and values of mixed types:

```
>>> mydict = {'1':1, 2:'2', 3:3}
>>> ", ".join("=".join((str(k),str(v))) for k,v in mydict.items())
'2=2, 3=3, 1=1'
```

Of course, for mixed types a plain `sorted()` will not work as expected. Use it only if you know all keys are strings (or all numeric, etc). In the former case, you can drop the first `str()` too:

```
>>> mydict = dict(a=1, b=2, c=2)
>>> ", ".join("=".join((k,str(v))) for k,v in sorted(mydict.items()))
'a=1, b=2, c=3'
```

Comment: The last one is same data format of my dictionary. But when I try you solution It returns this message : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @JihyeSeo: which one of my solutions are you trying, and what is your dict layout? I gave 3 alternatives: the simplest one requires both keys and values to be strings; the more robust one works with mixed data but can't be `sorted()`, and the last one expects uniform data (and string keys). It all depends on your data format.

Comment: @JihyeSeo: Given your error, quite possibly you named a variable `str`, shadowing the builtin `str` class. Don't use builtin names to name your objects!

Comment: The last one I used. I didn't use builtin str class. Anyway I solved it using different solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

In python 3.6 I prefer this syntax, which makes the code even more readable:

```
'<br/>'.join([f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in d.items()])
```

See [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to be ***more*** pythonic, we can remove the `for`-comprehension altogether.

```
'<br/>'.join(map(':: '.join, mydict.items()))
```

Comment: just 1 ```)``` is missing in the end:  ```'<br/>'.join(map(':: '.join, mydict.items()))```

Answer (score 1):

I liked what Filip Dupanović did above. I modified this to be python3-ish using `str.format` method.

```
'<br/>'.join(['{0}:: {1}'.format(key, value) for (key, value) in d.items()])
```

I modified the above to generate a string I could feed to a SQL table create statement.

```
fieldpairs = ','.join(['{0} {1}'.format(key, value) for (key, value) in HiveTypes.items()])
```