# Insert in a Database in python

Tags: python, database, sql-insert

I want to insert a dictionary `a = {'key': 602L}` into DB in python. It does not allows me to insert it because of the `quotes'' in key`.

Here is my query

```
self.__db_conn.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('%s')" % (str(a)))
```

If I manually try to insert it(without quotes), it does work.

```
self.__db_conn.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('%s')" % ("{key: 602L}"))
```

Note the missing quotes in key.

How do I insert a dictionary into a table.?

Comment: Why do you want to store a dict this way into a database? In doubt: serialize or deserialize using JSON a dict to a string and back but not this way.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519599/python-dictionary-to-string-custom-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize to JSON

```
self.__db_conn.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('%s')" % json.dumps(your_dict)
```

Unserialize from JSON

```
row = db.conn.fetchone(.....)
your_dict = json.loads(row[...])
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Yes I knew it before. For complete explanation, refer to another answer provide.

Answer (score 1):

`str(a)` is `"{'key': 602L}"`. Replacing this into the SQL statement gives:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('{'key': 602L}')
```

Note the mismatch of single quotes. Look into escaping the single quotes.

**EDIT**

As **user2799617** mentioned, you can try the following:

```
import json
a_json = json.dumps(str(a))
self.__db_conn.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('%s')" % a_json)
```

When you get the value back from the database, you can use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: Yaa I know. That is my concern. How do I store the full dictionary `with quotes` in DB?

Comment: Please read answers and seralize/deserialize your dict from and to JSON