# python: nested dictionary printing datetime as string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519599/python-dictionary-to-string-custom-format)

I have a dictionary that looks something like

```
times = {
 'on': 
    {'start': datetime.time(6, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>), 
     'end': datetime.time(8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)}
 'off':
    {'start': datetime.time(10, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>), 
     'end': datetime.time(13, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)}
}
```

calling `str(times)` gives

```
In[34]: str(f)
Out[34]: "{'on': {'start': datetime.time(6, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>), 'end': datetime.time(8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)}, 'off': {'start': datetime.time(10, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>), 'end': datetime.time(13, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)}}"
```

when I would like the datetimes to output as

```
In[37]: str(times['on']['start'])
Out[37]: '06:00:00'
```

AKA:

```
"{'on': {'start': '06:00:00, 'end': '08:00:00'}, 'off': {'start': '10:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'}}"
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
str({k: {k1: str(v1) for k1, v1 in v.items()} for k, v in times.items()})
```

Output looks something like this:

```
"{'on': {'start': '10:01:00', 'end': '10:01:00'}, 'off': {'start': '10:01:00', 'end': '10:01:00'}}"
```

It's a little gross since you essentially have to un-pack and then re-pack a nested dictionary, but it works. For arbitrarily nested data, you would need a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) with format string as: `"%H:%M:%S"`

Hence, in order to update your dict, do:

```
for key, nested_dict in times.items():
    for k in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[k] = nested_dict[k].strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

OR, use *dict comprehension* as:

```
{key: {k: v.strftime("%H:%M:%S") for k, v in nested_dict.items()} 
      for key, nested_dict in times.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier and works for any arbitrary dictionary:

```py
import json

times = { ... }
s = json.dumps(times, default=str)
print(s)
```

Comment: huh, I never knew about `dumps(default=)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for a subclass to control the string output of the time object:

You can do:

```
class MyTime(datetime.time):   
    def __repr__(self):
        return datetime.time.strftime(self, "%H:%M:%S")    


times = {
     'on': 
        {'start': MyTime(6, 0), 
         'end': MyTime(8, 0)},
     'off':
        {'start': MyTime(10, 0), 
         'end': MyTime(13, 0)}
    }
```

Then the formatting is automatic:

```
>>> times
{'on': {'start': 06:00:00, 'end': 08:00:00}, 'off': {'start': 10:00:00, 'end': 13:00:00}}
```

Yet the elements of your nested dict remain time objects:

```
>>> times['on']['start'].hour
6
```